# git: hook processed files?

Tags: git, githooks

Good evening
it's strange that git hooks obviously don't know anything about handled files, e.g.:

```
# Checkout any files which were deleted in the local workspace
git ls-files -d | xargs git checkout --
```

This command calls the post-checkout script - but does not pass all handled files.

Is there a solution to call a git hook for each handled file and the action happaned to it? (file was update, created, deleted, …)

Thanks a lot for any help!,
kind regards,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there aren't any out of the box hooks.

git hooks are triggered on certain actions happening, and from the [list of hooks mentioned in documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks), none of them deals with actions on specific files. All of these are actions at the project level, and do not deal with individual files.

Comment: Hi mu, thank you very much for your answer! We just moved to git and are wondering that it does not support basic things like handling file metadata or providing per file hooks. I'll look for a git feature request portal :-)